# "I lost my chems." What does it mean?

Tags: meaning

I heard this in [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1194173/) movie:

> I lost my chems.

What does it mean?

Tried via Google. But, found nothing about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the *Bourne Legacy*, *chem* is short for chemical treatments, their program medication.

From [Yahoo Voices](http://voices.yahoo.com/the-bourne-legacy-jeremy-renner-rachel-weisz-11725454.html):

> Aaron Cross (Jeremy Renner) is part of Operation Outcome a black ops program similar to Treadstone which enhances the physical and mental abilities of agents through chemicals treatments called "chems." ... The two team up to "viral" Cross off of his psychologically-enhancing chems so they can try to escape the Outcome purge.

If you watch the rest of the film, you'll hear them repeat it several times.

Comment: I can just add that not everyone in England - including me - would understand such a phrase. Maybe in context in a film, where "chemicals" had been discussed, but I have never heard anyone say "chems". But I am one of those sticklers who would not understand new slang expressions anyway...

Comment: @David - As an American, I can't remember hearing that word either. The typical word is "meds".